# app.config Assembly Binding seemingly being ignored

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly, app-config

I have a c# class library project that has several references to the Microsoft.Owin, Microsoft.IdentityModel and Microsoft.Graph assemblies.  The msbuild command is returning warnings of version conflicts.

For these assemblies I'm getting v6.5.0.0 conflicting with v5.3.0.0:

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect

System.IdentityModel.TOkens.Jwt

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols

I have this in my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.5.0.0" newVersion="6.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.5.0.0" newVersion="6.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.5.0.0" newVersion="6.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.5.0.0" newVersion="6.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

When I build I still get the version conflicts as if it's ignoring my binding redirects.

Any ideas?

Comment: does your csproj also modified?

Comment: Yes all the versions are updated in the project file.  Something like this... <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols, Version=6.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">